# Testing a Windows Form Application in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have created a Window Form Application that tests 2 input numbers. The out put must be according to this table:
[image: this table]

My current program created the expected output for all numbers except 7,5 . It gives me 1,2 instead of 6,7

I'm not sure what is causing this to happen.

Here is my code thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WhiteBox
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int one = int.Parse(tbInputOne.Text);
        int two = int.Parse(tbInputTwo.Text);
        clearOutput();
        runCal(one, two);
    }
    private void clearOutput(){
        tbOneA.Clear();
        tbOneB.Clear();
        tbTwoA.Clear();
        tbTwoB.Clear();
        tbThreeA.Clear();
        tbThreeB.Clear();
        tbFinalA.Clear();
        tbFinalB.Clear();

}
    private void runCal(int a, int b){
        if (a>=b){
            int temp = b;
            b = a;
            a = temp;
            tbOneA.Text = a.ToString();
            tbOneB.Text = b.ToString();
        }
        if ((Math.Cos(a)) == 0 || (Math.Cos(b) >= 0)){
            //Changed the < to == 
            a = 1;
            b = 3;
            tbTwoA.Text = a.ToString();
            tbTwoB.Text = b.ToString();
        }
        int x = (a + b) / 2;
        if (Math.Cos(x) > 0){
            a = x;
            tbThreeA.Text = a.ToString();

        }
        else {
            b = x;
            tbThreeB.Text = b.ToString();

        }
        tbFinalA.Text = a.ToString();
        tbFinalB.Text = b.ToString();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing. I'm sure it's a simple error but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the flow of runCal:

Enter with: a=7, b=5

```
if (a>=b) => (7>=5) => true
{
    swap(a,b)
}
```

After first if: a=5, b=7

```
if((Math.Cos(a)) == 0 || (Math.Cos(b) >= 0)) => (0.283662185 == 0 || (0.753902254 >= 0)) => false || true => true
{
    a=1, b=3
}
```

After second if: a=1, b=3

```
x = (a + b) / 2 = 2
if (Math.Cos(x) > 0) => (-0.416146837 > 0) => false
*here go to else
{
     b = x = 2
}
```

at the end: a=1, b=2

Comment: Can you explain this? I can't see it.

Comment: do you see it now?

Comment: I'm still not sure what I need to change

Comment: For all I know you can do  if ((a==7)&&(b==5)){tbFinalA.Text = 6;tbFinalB.Text = 7;return;} and it will work. You wrote "I'm not sure what is causing this to happen." now you do :)